# Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace when typing ng serve

Tags: angular

I am 100% sure i'm in root project but I still get this error after I did some update of angular cli and node. I have deleted node_modules, node.js, angular cli and reinstalled them, I have even crated a new app but nothing helps..any thoughts?

Comment: you have to run the command in `cmd or powershell`, where the path should be in the same folder as the `package.json`

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: try once npm run start it has a short cut script to ng serve,

Answer (score 1):

Was running into the same issue. I was 100% I was running the ng commands from the correct directory, but still getting the error. I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0bBLvWXBvc) intro to Angular tutorial and wondering what I could have done wrong.

For some reason, it looks like I didn't have an angular.json file in my root directory. After copying the file from the tutorials repo into my own, the commands worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this commands

```
npx ng serve
```

or

```
npm ng serve
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately